# Render image with shape overlay

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am new to opengl, and I am struggling with displaying multiple layers of objects on the screen. I am trying to display an image with different shapes on top of it. Right now what I have :

- A prototype code where the model draw the image in a given rectangle. I used the most recurrent concept where the fragment shader read color information from the texture

  ```
  in vec2 texCoord;
  out vec4 color;

  uniform sampler2D myTexture; 
  void main()
  {
      color = texture(myTexture, texCoord);
  }
  ```
- A prototype code which render shapes using a geometry shader. The number of shapes is very small ( a dozen ).

  ```
   //geometry shader stub
   layout(points) in;
   layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 5) out;

   in vec2    shapeDim[];
   void draw_rectangle(vec4 pos, float w, float h); //etc...

   void main()
   {
      draw_rectangle(gl_in[0].gl_Position, shapeDim[0].x, shapeDim[0].y);
   }
  ```

Now I am confused how to merge both  prototypes to have the shapes on top of the texture.

- Can\Should I use a single shader program? In this case how do I use the primitives I generated to conditionally get the texture color or overlay color (assume overlay color is constant for a start).
- Should I use separate shader programs\models? Ie use texture program, texture VAO, draw, use overlay program, overlay vao, draw, etc...
- Is there a better (clever/simpler/whatever) way to draw regular geometric figures than using a geometry shader in modern opengl (>= 4.0)?